# CSS object shows under other objects when zoom

Tags: html, css

CSS object shows under other objects when zoom, I want to make this above all css or html objects. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

**How is it zoomed:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNAzz.jpg

**How I want to be zoomed:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcPWy.jpg

**HTML CODE**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <br><center><li><a href="#"><img src="1.png" onmouseover="this.src='2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='1.png'" /></a></li></center>
    <center><li><div id="mmenu"><a href="#"><img src="1contact.png" onmouseover="this.src='2contact.png'" onmouseout="this.src='1contact.png'" /></a></div></li></center>
    <center><li><div id="mmenu"><a href="http://soccerway.ge/?cat=1"><img src="1news.png" onmouseover="this.src='2news.png'" onmouseout="this.src='1news.png'" /></a></div></li></center>
  </ul></nav>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #24933e;
  border-right:solid #176328;
  border-width:2px;
}

#mmenu {
  border-bottom:solid #176328;
  border-width:1px;
}
```

Comment: You can try using z-index in your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  [Z-index Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and assign to nav a higher z- index than others

```
 nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #24933e;
  border-right:solid #176328;
  border-width:2px;
  z-index:99;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `Z-index` to the `Nav`.

```
nav {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Begin with 1 and if it is still behind the mmenu then make it to 10 or even 100.